# what element type and layout for should I use for app landing page navigation buttons?

Tags: android-layout

I'm pretty new to Android Development, i'm following some Youtube tutorials currently. I'd like to create a basic mobile tourist application, but i'm stuck as to how to create the main menu layout.

Each Favorite 1 - 3, and Options 1 - 9 should be icons. (I'm not sure which form element should be used for this).

## Question

**How can I create the favorite, and option icons in the layout.xml file, what element is best suited, and what layout(s) should I use?**

In HTML, i'd create a table with 3 columns, 4 rows and set the table width and height to be 100%, and make the td valign and align central.

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you could make horizontal linearLayouts of vertical LineraLayouts of Image+TextView pairs.

The second range linear layouts would have

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Inside second range layouts you could use for image and text/view:

```
...for images:
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:layout_height="0dp"

... for texts
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

And the screen is nicely divided.